# Securing PDFs in a webserver from public access

Tags: php, mysql, security

I have a website storing personal data about people. All of this information is in a database and pages allowing access to this information is password protected. However, recently I am having to keep PDF files that contain some of this information. These PDFs are stored in a folder in a server. I have put an `index.html` in that folder so that lookup is prevented.

However, I am worried about website copiers like `HTTrack` that could do a recursive lookup. I dont have access to `.htaccess` as the hosting service does not allow this.

How can I store PDFs in a secured way? I am using `php` and `MySQL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an `index.html` file that will prevent the directory contents from being listed by the server. Now, you have to worry about people guessing the file names of your files. You can store them by cryptic names. Take a look at hash functions to generate random strings.

When you let a user download a file, you should use a PHP script to read the contents of the file and send a correct MIME header. You should not link directly to the cryptic names, to keep these names a secret. The PHP script can then do the correct validation of the users.

But first you should check if your host allows you to put files in a folder that is not publicly available. If you can store the files in a non-public folder you're in good shape.

Comment: what about a website copier that copies files recursively? Will it not get hold of PDFs, presumably cryptic names will not help here?

Comment: I don't see how it could. It looks for all links on the web page and recursively open these pages. If you never link to your PDF's, i.e. keep them hidden and unlisted, you should be good.

Comment: What if someone gets access to the links via a bookmark, browser history, inspecting the traffic on the wire (the original question doesn't specify the site is using SSL), or someone accidentally shares an email? The strategy in this answer is commonly referred to as "security through obscurity", and that's usually frowned upon. At the very least, make the links "single use" - they should expire after first use.

Answer (score 2):

apartridge had it right when he suggested you use a php script to write the file contents to the HTTP response instead of linking directly to the file.

However, when sensitive files need to be protected from unauthorized access, there is one more step: move the files to a directory on the server that is not accessible from the web. I'm not as familiar with php, so I'll use an asp.net site as an example, but you should be able to follow along just fine.

In Windows, a path to a website might be `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebsite\Index.html`

I would store the files in something like `C:\WebsiteFiles\` so those files simply aren't accessible from the web. Now you can control access through a php script and not have to worry about people or scripts guessing filenames.

Comment: This is mentioned in my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly - and please don't take offense at this - the fact you're asking this question suggests you are not qualified to write software dealing with personal information. Even if you get this particular issue right, you may be making other mistakes. I'd recommend spending some time on the [OWASP website](http://www.owasp.org) and get a basic understanding of web application security.

Next, you should not put the PDF files on a publicly accessible web folder. If someone forwards a URL (no matter how cleverly hashed the file name is) to someone who shouldn't have access to it, your security model breaks. Disallowing file enumeration is not enough - you should not allow anyone to access the PDF files without entering credentials.

You can do that most easily with an .htaccess file - and if your hosting provider doesn't support that, I'd question their suitability for a project hosting sensitive data.

If you really must, you can create a "pass-through" PHP script. So, if the URL is `http://myserver.com/personalPDF.php?personID=JoeBlogs`, the file personalPDF would use the following pseudo code

```
if user is not logged in
  redirect to log-in page

if user does not have access to requested document
  redirect to "unauthorized" page

set PDF mime type
read requested document from disk and send to client
```

In PHP, the last two lines are something like:

```
<?php
$file="JoeBlogs.pdf";
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$file);
header("Content-type: ".mime_content_type($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
?>
```